# Rust: create a vector of integers

Tags: rust

I have a vector `vec![val1, val2, val3, ..., valK]`, and I would like to create a vector that will contain integers from 1 to K (i.e., `vec![1, 2, 3, ...K]`). How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

**Collect** a **Range**:

```rust
(0u64..k).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a378f44b30cbb4832d5cc0267fcd9b9d)

Comment: This seems to work only for usize. For u32, or u64 (which is the one I need) it returns an error `value of type 'Vec<u64>' cannot be built from 'std::iter::Iterator<Item=usize>'`

Comment: @Ziva, mark the type in the range then, I updated it.

Comment: You'll get a conflict between `0u64` and the type of `k`. Rather use `(0 .. k as u64).collect::<Vec<_>>()`